# Spark Vector RDD creation without collecting to driver

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, apache-spark-mllib

I have a RDD[(User, Item, Count/Rating)] and I would like to convert it into an RDD[Vector(ItemRatings)] where each Vector is a the item's ratings in the user space. Is there a way to do this without collecting to driver first? I am using Datastax 4.7, Spark 1.2.1 currently.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `RDD.groupByKey` not what you're looking for?

Comment: What is your RDD[Vector(ItemRatings)] exactly since you have three entities that are User, Item and Rating. What is the ItemRatings entity? What does it represent?

Comment: Each row in the RDD[Vector(ItemRatings)] is a single user's ratings vector.   @DanielDarabos - groupByKey would have worked except I need it converted to a Vector for column similarity functions on RowMatrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both `User` and `Item` are encoded as `Long` values you can use `CoordinateMatrix`.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val mat: CoordinateMatrix = new CoordinateMatrix(
  rdd.map{case (user, item, rating) => MatrixEntry(item, user, rating)}
)

val vectorRDD: RDD[Vector] = mat.toRowMatrix.rows
```

Comment: thanks .. thats a useful solution. Unfortunately, User and Item and Strings .. but I guess I could transform to Long if there isn't an alternative.

Comment: You can use `groupBy` as mentioned by [Daniel Darbos](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3318517/daniel-darabos) but you'll still need a mapping between `user` and index in vector.